# Context' object has no attribute 'embed'

Tags: python-3.x, discord

I am developing a discord robot and I currently have an embed problem as I am trying to retrieve information from whether or not the person to check a reaction to then run an information

```
 author = ctx.message.author
    embed = discord.Embed(title = "__Voici les pseudos que vous pouvez avoir :__ ", colour = discord.Colour.purple())
    embed.set_author(name = ctx.author.name, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url)
    embed.add_field(name ="`Ascii`:space_invader:", value = nom_ascii ,inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name ="`Hexa`:abcd:", value = nom_hex ,inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name ="`Binaire`:keycap_ten:", value = nom_bin ,inline = True)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/843519942518243368/843864950048948254/bjR6ASaFUlZkooq9bm4MMbbZ9H63kdenFJktLDy32Glh_rBAIeGNm9OB6HP3_5LslmtXU1RrZXPoN_cT5_dfaUYaPfZmiy0.png")


    message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await message.add_reaction("")
    await message.add_reaction("")
    await message.add_reaction("")

    def checkEmoji(reaction, user):
        return ctx.embed.author == user and embed.id == reaction.embed.id and (str(reaction.emoji) == "" or str(reaction.emoji) == "" or str(reaction.emoji) == "")

    reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout = 10, check = checkEmoji)
    if reaction.emoji == "":
        await member.edit(nick=nom_ascii)
    if reaction.emoji == "":
        await member.edit(nick=nom_hex)
    if reaction.emoji == "":
        await member.edit(nick=nom_bin)
```

N.B : the code is in french

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share the full error, in order to trace exactly where the error occurs.

Comment: i found the answer at the end